# get parent object filter by nested child fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside teacher, there is child subject, and subject has a child student. I want to get all teachers filter by `student_name`. Teacher object can be something like this:

```
{ "id": 5,
  "name": "teacher-one",
  "gender": "male",
  "subject": {
    "id": 10,
    "subject_name": "Maths",
    "student": {
      "id": 1,
      "student_name": "student-one", 
       "grade" : "one",
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking to filter this out by using find method, something like
`Teacher.find(:all, params: {gender: "male'})` which returns all the male teachers. But the following code does not work:

```rb
Teacher.find(:all, params: { subject: { student: grade == "one" }})
```

Comment: can you provide the model files for both student and teacher?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Teacher.joins(subject: :student).where(student: {student_name: "Bala"})
```

Comment: I tried using joins, but i kept on getting undefined method 'joins'

Comment: what is your Teacher's superclass?

Comment: Yes Teacher does have a superclass, its School. Do i have to use joins with superclass? Thank you for your time to answer.

Comment: can you tell me what is your rails version or other develop environment or anything else

Comment: rails version we are using is 4.2.2, and server side is using Java. the collection type of the Teacher is ActiveResource::Collection.

Comment: I think you can use th custom method, for detail : https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/classes/ActiveResource/CustomMethods.html